# Prove that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a} f(x) \ dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, continuity

If $f(x)$ is a real valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $a>2$ is arbitrary then prove that $$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a} f(x) \ dx=0$$
My attempt: Since $f$ is continuous on closed interval $[a-\varepsilon,a]$ so $f$ is bounded and there exists some $M>0$ such that $$|f(x)|\leq M \ \ \ \text{for all}\ \ \ x\in [a-\varepsilon,a]$$
So we have by triangle inequality $$\left|\int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a} f(x) \ dx\right|\leq M\varepsilon$$ So we obtain $$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a-\varepsilon}^{a} f(x) \ dx=0$$
but the problem I think is that $M$ can depend on $\varepsilon$.

Any help is desired. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take $M$ to be a bound for $|f|$ on $[a-1,a]$. Your inequality is now valid for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $M$ is independent of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. But how is $M$ independent of epsilon?

Comment: By definition $M=\sup \{|f(x)|: a-1 \leq x \leq a\}$. This has nothing to do with $\epsilon$. @Nirvana

Comment: Thank you. One last question what if in the end we have to take $a\to \infty$? Then also the proof works?

Comment: Why are you taking supremum? Will maximum won't work?

Comment: superemum and maximum are same because of continuity. @Nirvana

Comment: And what if in the last we take $a\to +\infty$?

Comment: For that you have to assume that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$ @Nirvana

Comment: So your proof works for any $a>2$ or any finite $a>2$?

Comment: In the question $a$ is given to be a fixed real number greater than $2$. You are not asked to take limit as $a \to \infty$. @Nirvana